# How to use userPrincipalName with kerberos in Keycloak?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, keycloak, kerberos

I have several user federations with different domains in keylock. The userprincipalname attribute is used as the username. In one federation I want to use Kerberos, I configure it, but the login does not work. From the logs I see that Kerberos passes the samaccountname as the username. If in the federation settings I change the user name to samaccountname, then everything works without problems. What can you do?

I can not try something, because I do not know what I should try.